# Django Display ID and Description From Queryset Form into Dropdown

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I would like to display data from the table into Django Queryset Form with properly showing value and text of dropdown control.

Coding at Form:

```
self.fields['testing_field'].queryset = model_abc.objects.all().values_list('description', flat=True)
```

Result description is also value:

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Result expection can set id as value with existing description:

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

How to set id as a value within the dropdown form of Django QuerySet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch both the description and the pk of the objects. that's easy enough:

```
 possibles = model_abc.objects.all().values_list('pk', 'description')
```

You might convert this into a dynamic choices:

```
 choices = ( (x['pk'], x['description']) for x in possibles )
```

or, you might iterate over possibles in your template

```
 {% for option in possibles %}
     <option value="{{option.pk}}">{{option.description}}</option>
 {% endfor %}
```